# Custom TCP proxy for high availability cluster

Tags: tcp, proxy, high-availability

I'm in a high availability project which includes deployment of 2-node high availability cluster for hot replacement of services (applications) running on the cluster nodes. The applications have inbound and outbound tcp connections as well as process udp traffic (mainly for communicating with ntp server).

The problem is pretty standard until one needs to provide a hot migration of services to backup node with all the data stored in RAM. Applications are agnostic of backup mechanisms and it is highly undesirable to modify them.

As only approach to this problem, I've come off with a duplication approach assuming that both cluster nodes will run the same applications repeating calculations of each other. In case of failure the primary server the backup server will become a primary.

However, I have not found any ready solution for proxy which will have synchronous port mirroring. No existing proxy servers (haproxy, dante, 3proxy etc.) support such feature as far as I know. Have I missed something, or I should write a new one from scratch?

A rough sketch of the functionality can be found here:

[image]

p.s. I assume that it is possible to compare traffic from the two clones of the same application...

Comment: are you looking for a proxy that will fail over a connection to a different back-end if the first one goes down, or are you looking for something else (e.g. that would mirror the data in the first place).  If the former, we have a product that will allow failover to the back end, if the latter I don't know of anything.

Comment: @Adrien we need a solution to provide full synchronous mirroring of proxy ports attached to backend. That is all packets coming out of those ports will be synchronous over all ports, and packets coming in from backend will be reduced and forwarded to their destinations.

Comment: Hi, so say you have 2 back end servers, you have a proxy that connects to both and if it receives a message it forwards it to both back ends?  Then discards one of the responses (since you probably don't want the client to see 2 responses to 1 request)?  Is the back end a database?  There may need to be protocol specific handling for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @Adrien, nope that is not a DB endpoint. Yep, proxy have to discards messages from the secondary server as well as to duplicate incoming messages. Also it needs to synchronize connections (that is to stall messages from primary servers until their counterpart from secondary is received).

Comment: OK, so it sounds like the intermediary needs to be able to at least understand the framing on the messages.  This would need to be written specifically for the client-server protocol you're using.  Whether there exists one already or not, without knowing which protocol you're talking about we can't answer that.  Our product (WinGate) has a plugin API you could probably use to write something like this, not sure whether other proxy products also have an API for that sort of thing.  If you can avoid having to build all the infrastructure around this function you'd save yourself a lof of work.